# How to populate excel worksheet dynamically with activex controls?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a requirement where i have to dynamically place activex controls on my worksheet because there are too many controls to be placed on userform.

I have figured out a way to do so using :

```
Worksheets(1).OLEObjects.Add ClassType:="Forms.ListBox.1"
```

But how can i assign functions/macros to various events associated with that control. Eg. If i insert spin button dynamically at runtime how can program its events.

Comment: I would suggest against ActiveX controls - better use Forms Controls. You can easily create these controls and set the procedure to run (`ctrl.OnAction = "MyProc"`) or remove it (`ctrl.OnAction = ""`). Working with ActiveX controls is a mess since you have to create code in ugly way and you won't avoid flickering during this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub

Public Sub AddWorksheetEventCode()
    'Tools > references > Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3
    'Trust access to VBA model

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim xPro As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim xCom As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim xMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim xLine As Long
    Set wsNew = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With wsNew
              .OLEObjects.Add ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", _
 Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=40, Top:=40, _
 Width:=150, Height:=20
         '<==== This section adds the event to the project
        Set xPro = wb.VBProject
        Set xCom = xPro.VBComponents("Sheet1") '<== Defining the location to add
        Set xMod = xCom.CodeModule

        With xMod
            xLine = .CreateEventProc("Click", "CommandButton1") '<== Defining the event to add
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "test" '<== Defining the text within the event code i.e. calling the sub
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

---

In the above I have an existing procedure in a standard module called `test`. This is the sub (macro) that I am going to associate with the CommandButton.

---

### Objectives:

As per your question, as I understand it, you want to

1. Programmatically add an ActiveX object
2. Programmatically add events to this object

---

### 1. Adding the object

The   `.OLEObjects.Add`  section adds the command button.

---

### 2. Adding the event(s)

The section from  `Set xPro = wb.VBProject`  downwards is what constructs the event (CommandButton Click) and fills that event with the command that calls the sub `test`. The VBIDE is how you interact programmatically to create project components like events.

> The VBIDE is the object library that defines all the objects and
>   values that make up VBProject and the Visual Basic Editor. <sub>[source](http://Programming%20The%20VBA%20Editor)</sub>

**a.** Defining the location to add

`Set xCom = xPro.VBComponents("Sheet1")`

**b.** Defining the event to add

`xLine = .CreateEventProc("Click", "CommandButton1")`

**c.** Defining the text within the event code i.e. calling the sub

```
.InsertLines xLine, "test"
```

### **Edit:**

Better still would be to define a class to handle all of this. Define methods etc in there.

---

Example of setting properties of the object; First, put the object into a variable when adding then refer to that variable when later working with its properties e.g.

```
Dim b As Object

    With wsNew
            Set b = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", _
 Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=40, Top:=40, _
 Width:=150, Height:=20)

        Set xPro = wb.VBProject
        Set xCom = xPro.VBComponents("Sheet1")
        Set xMod = xCom.CodeModule

        With xMod
            xLine = .CreateEventProc("Click", "CommandButton1")
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "test"
        End With
    End With

   b.Height = 150
```

**Caveat:**

Picking up on the important point raised by @MathieuGuindon - this [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) is bug-prone and you won't be able to simply debug.

Comment: Let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: It would be appreciable if you could explain it a bit.

Comment: Will put some notes in now

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i have some doubt.

Actually i managed to insert the activex controls dynamically but by some other method. It puts several buttons on the sheet depending on the conditions. Sometimes 4 buttons or 5 depending on condition.

I have to implement change and mousemove events for my controls but i want to put the code dynamically into these events for every control.

Will this work in my case?

Comment: In general with the construct I have shown above yes. It is the way you work to add events. You would need to define correctly for the type of events you are interested in. I am not familiar with mousemove events but suspect that may require add in API call information to the host OS.

Comment: Thanks very much. It worked as desired but i want to manipulate the properties of the created control. When i try to do so it says "Object Required"

How can i approach this problem?

Comment: If you set the added object to a variable e.g. Set b =  .OLEObjects.Add .... then after alter b with b.Property = .... etc

Comment: @user3906724 as you can see, this type of meta-programming (i.e. a macro that writes itself at run-time) isn't for the faint-hearted, and very likely bug-prone, and the dynamically added code won't be debuggable, and then you need to account for what happens if the macro is invoked twice. If possible I would warmly recommend using form controls instead, and assigning an *existing* (compile-time existing, I mean) public procedure to its `OnAction` property.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Absolutely agreed! In fact I was a little anxious about even the above as answer given exactly what you said about if macro invoked twice.

Comment: Glad. Just be wary about how glitchy these things can be.

Comment: It works fine but sometimes it gives error on Set xCom = xPro.VBComponents("Sheet1"). I have checked several times . I have entered correct sheet name